# Angular Component insertion in svg-tag

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I would like to find out if I can place an angular-component within the svg-tag. The purpose for this task is to create a nested svg which would otherwise end up in a very big inline html-file. So I would like to find a way to solve this issue and separate the big svg file into multiple components, as these svg's are overlay each other I just have to add a function that only one is shown up. I can not the component after each other as the svg-images are nested.

At the moment I can create a component of each svg, but as I can not use the  within the svg the image is created component by component and not nested as I want to. I have attached an image which hopefully shows the problem which I would like to solve.

```
<div class="container-fluid w-75">
  <app-component></app-component>
  <svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1366 768">
  <!--Frame-->
    <g id="Frame">
      <path d="M1346,165V675a20,20,0,0,1-20,20H0v53a20,20,0,0,0,20,20H1346a20,20,0,0,0,20-20V165Z" fill="#d3d3d3" />
      <path d="M1266,27h0a6,6,0,0,0,6,6h57a5,5,0,0,1,5,5V95a6,6,0,0,0,6,6h0a6,6,0,0,0,6-6V33a12,12,0,0,0-12-12h-62A6,6,0,0,0,1266,27Z" fill="#00970e" />
      <path d="M100,742h0a6,6,0,0,0-6-6H37a5,5,0,0,1-5-5V674a6,6,0,0,0-6-6h0a6,6,0,0,0-6,6v62a12,12,0,0,0,12,12H94A6,6,0,0,0,100,742Z" fill="#00970e" />
      <path d="M20,736V593a10,10,0,0,0-10-10h0A10,10,0,0,0,0,593V748H0a20,20,0,0,0,20,20H175a10,10,0,0,0,10-10h0a10,10,0,0,0-10-10H32A12,12,0,0,1,20,736Z" fill="#003750" />
      <path d="M1346,33V176a10,10,0,0,0,10,10h0a10,10,0,0,0,10-10V21h0a20,20,0,0,0-20-20H1191a10,10,0,0,0-10,10h0a10,10,0,0,0,10,10h143A12,12,0,0,1,1346,33Z" fill="#003750" />
    </g>
  <app-component></app-component>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Test of `<foreignObject>` --> seems not to work:

```
<foreignObject><app-component></app-component></foreignObject>
```

[Principal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FoVS.png)
[Inline svg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQzHg.png)

[image]

Comment: Principally I want to create something like: <svg><my-component></my-component></svg>

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck here? What code have you written that's not working?

Comment: Hello Robert, I have added an image which shows that <my-component></my-component> (angular 8 component) works fine if I place it before the svg-tag, in the case I place it within the svg-tag I can not use it. As I want to reduce the size of my big inline html (due to the graphics into sub-svg's component for each child) it would be beneficial to work in this way, unfortunately I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: what does mycomponent do? If it renders as HTML it will need to be inside a <foreignObject> tag.

Comment: My Component is a sub-svg which I have created as Angular-Component, it seems not to work using <foreignObject> tag. Probably I should have written <app-component>

Comment: We really need to see what app-component does in order to help you.

Comment: could you maintain them as two separate components, each rendering one of the SVGs, and then use CSS to position one on top of the other? If, as I understand, you sometimes want to make only one of them visible, you could do that via CSS as well.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to try to position them on top of each other in css, have not tried this until now, I will try to test this suggestion and give an feedback soon.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: I thought to toggle the SVG's via CSS: style="display:none" and use a relative css class with -z value to bring it in the right position, but how could I bring the first one if I use the :target pseudo class to enable the change javascript click events. Another approach would be to use Angular CDK, but it seems not so easy to implement? Any idea about a CSS solution?

Comment: @To_Am Use CSS classes instead of using styles directly. Then you can swap the CSS classes on the SVG elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the overlay of two div-elements using css the grid class:

```
.container_row {
    display: grid;
}
.navigation-layer {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.content-layer {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

and I toggle the div via javascript and the display: none/block on and off. This results overlays the div very well.